# Foreground Events not recording with Java record replay protocol in Vugen(HP Load Runner)

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp, loadrunner, vugen

I have a JavaWS application which makes the client server calls through plain socket communication. My application launches through a JNLP file.

I'm trying to record this application using vugen java record replay protocol.

To record the communication which is using plain socket communication, i wrote custom java hooks in user.hooks file. 
But still vugen is not able to detect any events.

Could somebody please help me out here

Thanks in advance

Tejnadh Reddy

Answer (score 0):

What application layer protocol or port numbers are expressed when you look at the communication between client and server using a protocol analyzer such as Wireshark?

Comment: Thanks for your response James!!!
The application is using tcp protocol at transport level and mostly telnet at application layer level.

The Destination port is constant i.e, the server port src:45007 and the src ports i.e,client ports are getting changed for each activity.

Comment: Then build a telnet virtual user if it is just connecting to a terminal under the covers.   File => New +> RTE.   Connect to the terminal with the appropriate credentials and walk through the process.   No Java Complications.  Heck, you could even record straight non-encrypted telnet with Winsock.

You should expect the client ports to change, this is what is called a transient port number, distinct for each client.  The server port is the well known port, DST.  Take a look at that and confirm that it matches Telnet, which is port 23

Comment: But here there are lots of alerts and pollers runs in the background which is again a java activity..to capture these background activities we need java rr protocol ryt...?

I tried all other protocols to capture background class loading,alert requests and pollers..only with java rr protocol I was able to record them.

James I would like to know your opinion on using custom java hooks for my issue..on how to make this users.hook file work.

Anyhow I will try whatever you mentioned Thanks for the response james

Comment: I for one do not think you have telnet, otherwise you would just open up a terminal session and record the user interaction that way.   The telnet session does not care whether it is a user or a piece of Java code exercising the telnet interface

Comment: Yes,james i tried it with winsock port no.23 but its not woking out. Its not using telnet it seems.

Im trying to figure out which protocol its using at application layer level.

But as i said before james,since its a java webstart application the background class loading etc..need to be recorded an thats only possible with java record and replay..i also got inputs from hp guys who stated that using custom java hooks to record the socket communication would be a better option. I tried and its not working out too...any insights on this

Comment: What well known server port is involved?  When you record Winsock what server type and port is identified in the handshake (first five buffers).   You can't find a solution until you know the communication architecture.  Web Services, Sockets, RM/I, CORBA, telnet, ... They all have different paths.

Comment: i tried to record the communication as you told...but each time i try to record the tool is going to not responding state.

Comment: What well known server port is involved in the client conversation

Comment: 45007 is the well known server port involved in the conversation

Comment: Are you certain this is not the client/ephemeral port and not the server port?   Here is a list of well known ports

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers.  

There is nothing registered to that port which implies custom.   Then it's starting with Winsock or the published API set of the service team

Comment: http://www.adminsub.net/tcp-udp-port-finder/45007

you can have all the info about the port at this link

Comment: so what should i do now...?
could you please provide any insights on how to solve my issue

Comment: Go to the logs on the server to see what has been called and with what parameters.  Get the API from the developers.   Write code with the appropriate API calls and parameters to reproduce the behavior observed in the logs

Comment: which protocol i have to use...?

Is it java RR or winsock...?

Comment: If you are hand writing the virtual user, then you will be using a virtual user type which supports the API of your interface

Comment: Sure i will try that. but james what do you think of recording the socket communication with the java RR protocol using the custom java hooking...?

Is it feasible to follow the custom java hooks...?

Comment: Go for it, if you can figure out the dark magic of LoadRunner and Java.  I would just go to Winsock myself. Far simpler as every communication has to go through a socket.

Comment: When I'm trying to record using winsock protocol vugen is going to not responding state...my system has an 8 gb ram...how can I make this recording work james ?

Comment: Well, if no recording model works, then you will be writing code